# SparkJava GET Handler Returning NULL After Serialization of Long

Tags: java, gson, okhttp, spark-java

I'm trying to write a simple server with SparkJava but I am having considerable difficulty serialize a long using Gson and transmitting the JSON to an OkHttp client program inside a GET handler. The server returns NULL, more specifically response.body.string() is

```
<html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html>
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be? thanks.

Here is the GET handler:

```java
get("routingEngine/getDefaultRoute/distance", (request,response) ->{
    response.type("application/json");
    long distance = 100;
    return gson.toJson(distance);
});
```

Here is the client code making the simple request (please disregard the parameters (requestParameters) being passed in along with the request, they just provide information to an irrelevant before filter):

```java
    // build url
    HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .host("127.0.0.1")
    .port(4567)
    .addPathSegment("routingEngine")
    .addPathSegment("getDefaultRoute")
    .addPathSegment("distance")
    .build();

    // build request
    Request getDefaultRouteDistanceRequest = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .post(RequestBody.create(JSON,gson.toJson(requestParameters)))
    .build();

    // send request
    Call getDefaultRouteDistanceCall = httpClient.newCall(getDefaultRouteDistanceRequest);
    Response getDefaultRouteDistanceResponse = getDefaultRouteDistanceCall.execute();
    
    // parse response
    // testing
    System.out.println(getDefaultRouteDistanceResponse.body().string());
```

The last line leads to the following output

```
<html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html>
```

Comment: Could it be because you're creating a get endpoint and then using a post request in the call?

Comment: Yes, thanks @Vishal! Feel free to make that an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint you created was a GET endpoint and the call being made is for POST.